# Google Play store: Discount for in app purchases

Tags: google-play, in-app-billing

I developed an app with a simple implementation of google in-app purchases: the App is free and can be upgraded to a premium version via In App Billing (managed product) providing some additonal features.

Now I want to provide a special deal selling my in app product for half price for some days (maybe using a general promition code, but that's not important).

I did a lot of research and found a solution how to create a promotion for in-app purchases (for free) using promo codes, or how to set an app on sale (only available for chargeble apps).

Isn't there any posibility providing a special offer for my product?

Thanks a lot for your answer!

Raspberry

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Register another in-app product with a reduced price, make it available in the app on some days only. This will be quite open to user fraud, though - change the current date on the device, and enjoy the discount any day. That's barring more sophisticated kinds of fraud, like attaching with a debugger.

If it was possible to change the price on an IAP product from the app, there would be another massive avenue for attacks.

In general, when it comes to Android billing, [you can't trust the device](https://rathertech.blogspot.com/2016/12/google-play-fraud.html).

One safe way to do that would be to run a back-end with a connection to Google Play (either HTML scraping or API) that would modify the price on a schedule. I had some good results running Google Play console in headless Chrome driven by Puppeteer (and before that, in PhantomJS).